# Checkbox not set checked with match value on body load

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

Here I want to ask you about my checkbox.

I have an checkbox that the value get from database. So if value match, then the checkbox will checked.

Now I facing the problem when it should be checked but the checkbox not checked.

I see the problem in my body on load but I dont know how to fix it. How do I know the problem from there ? because if I refresh the page 2 or 3 times, the checkbox will checked after that checkbox uncheck again.

and here is my JS code :

```
function ActionCcdCheck (theForm)
    {
        if (theForm.ccd_chk.checked)
        {
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][0].className = 'part';
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][1].className = 'part';
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][2].className = 'part';

            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][0].disabled  = false;
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][0].checked  = false;
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][1].disabled  = false;
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][1].checked  = false;
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][2].disabled  = false;
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][2].checked  = false;
        }
        else
        {
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][0].disabled  = true;
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][1].disabled  = true;
            theForm['ccd_pos[]'][2].disabled  = true;
        }
    }

function LoadCondition ()
{
    ActionCcdCheck  (document.form);
}
```

and here is my checkbox code :

```
<body onload="LoadCondition();">
<form>
<?php
if(strpos($q_ccd_pos, 'front') === false)
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ccd_pos[]' value='front' class='part' onkeypress='FocusChange (this.form, 6, 3);'/> Front";
}
else
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ccd_pos[]' value='front' class='part' onkeypress='FocusChange (this.form, 6, 3);' checked/> Front";
}

if(strpos($q_ccd_pos, 'back') === false)
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ccd_pos[]' value='back' class='part' onkeypress='FocusChange (this.form, 7, 2);'/> Back";
}
else
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ccd_pos[]' value='back' class='part' onkeypress='FocusChange (this.form, 7, 2);' checked/> Back";
}

if(strpos($q_ccd_pos, 'fb') === false)
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ccd_pos[]' value='fb' class='part' onkeypress='FocusChange (this.form, 8, 1);'/> FB";
}
else
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ccd_pos[]' value='fb' class='part' onkeypress='FocusChange (this.form, 8, 1);' checked/> FB";
}
?>
</form>
</body>
```

Please advice.
Thank you

Comment: You have no `<form...`, or did you leave that out?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I have updated that

Comment: Plus, you have no `<?php` tags anywhere.

Comment: I assumed all understand about that. Now my problem is when I refresh page 2 or more times, the checkbox will see checked. Like I said the  problem maybe from my on load..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see your checkbox `ccd_chk` to test for:

```
 if (theForm.ccd_chk.checked)
```

so i create one :

```
<form>
<?php
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ccd_chk' value='chk' class='part' checked /> chk\n";
if(strpos($q_ccd_pos, 'front') === false)
[...]
```

This is obviously wrong

```
if (theForm.ccd_chk.checked)
```

replace with

```
if (theForm['ccd_chk'].checked )   {
```

replace also in `LoadCondition ()`

```
function LoadCondition ()
{
    ActionCcdCheck  (document.form);
}
```

with

```
    ActionCcdCheck(document.forms[0]);
```

Now it should work :-)